# Computer malfunctioning

Tags: windows-7, laptop, crash

I'm very much disturbed with the way my laptop is behaving these days, which includes:

Frequently bluescreen, sudden shutdown, sluggish speed, applications mal-functioning.

As suggested by computer technicians, already changed battery and hard-disk very recently, but problem still persists. [Clearly no issue with HDD and battery]

Can't exactly figure out where exactly the issue is.

Can anyone help me out in this.

I can understand the reason could be many, but there should be some way to test my system to figure out where is the center of the problem.

I'm using DELL STUDIO-1555 2009 model, Core 2 duo, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD, Win7.

Comment: You can not have bad sectors in a computer. You can have bad sectors on a harddisk. Since you wrote that they already replaced the harddisk it is possible that you have a problem with the connectors between the motherboard and the disk. Check those. Also check the event logs (start, run, `eventvwr.msc`. Look for errors in the [Windows logs] part).

Comment: Have you run Dell's PSA diagnostics?

Comment: Did you check memory with MemTest? The systems you describe sound to me like software conflicts. Are your drivers up-to-date or did you recently update drivers? What stuff have you got running in the background that you can temporarily disable to exclude it as the cause? What are the chances of having a virus infection?

Comment: @Hennes I hope HDD is an important part of an integrated PC.

Comment: For the -2, just a question: Why?

Comment: Have you run the integrated Dell diagnostics?  You can set the diagnostics to runs several times to test for intermittent issues.

Answer (score 4):

One cause that comes to my mind for all 4 symptoms is bad memory.
Windows has a memory testing program it self which can be run when booting.
[Here](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/tutorial-how-to-use-memtest.62524/) is a tutorial about running the memory test.

Another possible cause for some of these issues (like BSOD and sudden shutdown) is a bad video card or a bad video connection. Either the card can become to hot or it has bad memory.
[Here](http://www.technibble.com/repair-tool-of-the-week-video-memory-stress-test/) is a video card memory tester.

Another cause could be the environment of your laptop, this may sound weird but if you have a large magnet or something like that close to your laptop, your CPU might start acting weird. This was sometimes an issue in the 90's and before, haven't heard of it since then though. There could also be some power leaking causing interference with the CPU frequency with the northbridge or ram.

Another cause could be wrong BIOS version, try updating your BIOS.
[Here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/187437/how_to_update_your_bios.html) is an example of how to do that.

The answers aren't very concrete, but I hope it will help you a bit more in the right direction.

Remember: That you have multiple problems on the same time doesn't mean there is one cause, it could be multiple causes as well.

Comment: Sounds like RAM most likely, but you are absolutely right that there may be more than one issue. Fantastic links, bookmarking that for my own uses. +1